# Is it reliable to check for a certain structure in getFilesDir() directory in Android?

Tags: android, directory

I'd like to check certain things in that directory to check user has not somehow accessed that directory and has changed something on his own.

In order to do that I'm excluding some files that services my app uses creates in that directory, like, for example realm database files or google maps config files. Code is prepared so that certain files would be excluded from raising that the user has modified something in the directory in his own.

Problem is that it looks like files are not always the same, for example in my physical device a new folder and 2 files that are not created in emulator get created.

If different files can be created depending on if you are using one device or another, then this is not going anywhere, and I'll have to think in another approach for the problem we need to make this check, but if the only difference is that only these files and folder appear in physical devices with the same name as the one I'm seeing, it would just be question of also excluding them.

So, what can I expect about the files created in that directory in physical devices?

Comment: "to check user has not somehow accessed that directory" -- outside of rooted devices, users have no ability to access `getFilesDir()`. "for example in my physical device a new folder and 2 files that are not created in emulator get created" -- are you sure that you are looking in `getFilesDir()`? You do not have access to that either, except on rooted devices or, for a `debug` build of your app, using tools like Device File Explorer in Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm precisely using a debug build of my app, and we'd like to avoid user using a rooted device to change content, user may always fool the app checkings by setting fake files appropiately, but at leader we'd like to make it hard.

Comment: `Problem is that it looks like files are not always the same, for example in my physical device a new folder and 2 files that are not created in emulator get created.` Names please.

Comment: What does it matter that there are some extra folders and files? As long as you can check your own folders and files you are done i would say.

Comment: If the user has root, then you can't assume the user didn't change a file.  You can do things to try and detect it (for example, checksuming the file and checking it at boot), but that assumes he didn't edit the checksum as well.  In the end, if you don't control the hardware you can't trust the filesystem.  All you can do is put up speedbumps making it a bit more of a pain in the neck to do.  Even relying on encryption and secure storage, they can use a version of AOSP that doesn't actually do that and pretends it does.